# SQL -- Calculating Age from Birthday Record

Tags: mysql, sql

The following is my attempt at calculating the birthday from the person who is the oldest in my table:

```
select firstname, 
datediff(year(curtime()), min(year(birthday))) 
from TABLE_A ;
```

The query returns NULL.

I suppose that I have forgotten how this is done. I am more than likely missing something simple.

Comment: What RDBMS is this ??

Answer (score 1):

**Mysql**

```
SELECT year(NOW())-  year(birthday))  
FROM table WHERE condition 
ORDER BY dateField ASC LIMIT 1
```

**Sql Server**

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthday, GETDATE())
FROM Table_A
ORDER BY birthday ASC
```

Comment: `CURTIME()` isn't what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `DATEDIFF()` should be *dates*; whereas the result of `YEAR()` is an integer representing only a date's year.  If you are looking to obtain the age of the eldest person in `TABLE_A`, you can use MySQL's [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, MIN(birthday), CURRENT_DATE) FROM TABLE_A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),MIN(birthday))) FROM TABLE_A
```

or

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, MIN(birthday), NOW()) FROM TABLE_A
```

[This list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) of MySQL date and time functions will be useful.

Comment: I wouldn't use `NOW()` because we typically consider that it's their birthday all day.

Comment: Does that really matter? The age is being based on the year value. What would you recommend to use instead?